# When Boromir was fighting in Osgiliath, what shield would he have used?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

When Boromir was not travelling with the fellowship, would he have used a different shield. Can it be said that his round shield seen the the films was a "travel shield"? When he was fighting at Osgiliath, for instance, he would have used the same shield as is used by the generic warriors of Minas Tirith?

It is seen that he wears similar heavy armor like the common warriors wear although his is much more ornate so would he have used a similar shield as well?
Is it common for a soldier to bear the same shield in all cases like a sword?

Comment: I've read several reviews that indicate that this book (http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Lord-Rings-Weapons-Warfare/dp/000717201X) contains information about the weapon and armour choices for each of the characters. According to [this thread](http://www.swordforum.com/forums/showthread.php?31061-Boromirs-round-shield) his round shield was intended to distinguish him in battle and was therefore his normal shield.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is unknown.

Much of the Osgiliath episode is a movie invention, so there's no source in the books to say whether Boromir would have used the same, a different, or even any shield at all when not with the Fellowship.

In the books Boromir's shield is actually not described at all (it's not even said to be round, which is commonly assumed, I believe, based on the Brothers Hildebrandt illustration of the Fellowship); the only thing that is said of it is in the description of Boromir's equipment when leaving Rivendell:

> Boromir had a long sword, in fashion like Andúril but of less lineage and he bore also a shield and his war-horn.

Crucially, in the scene where Boromir's funeral boat is described, his shield is *not* included among the various items arrayed about him (despite this description being detailed enough to include the fact that Boromir also wore a helmet when with the Fellowship):

> Now they laid Boromir in the middle of the boat that was to bear him away. The grey hood and elven-cloak they folded and placed beneath his head. They combed his long dark hair and arrayed it upon his shoulders. The golden belt of Lorien gleamed about his waist. His helm they set beside him, and across his lap they laid the cloven horn and the hilts and shards of his sword; beneath his feet they put the swords of his enemies.

The reason for this is obvious, as we learn in Aragorn's second verse of his departure song:

> Beneath Amon Hen I heard his cry. There many foes he fought.
>   His cloven shield, his broken sword, they to the water brought.

Despite this, Faramir doesn't seem to have noticed it's absence when he came across Boromir's body (this is shown as if it were a dream-sequence in the Extended Edition of the Two Towers):

> A broken sword was on his knee. I saw many wounds on him. It was Boromir, my brother, dead. I knew his gear, his sword, his beloved face. One thing only I missed: his horn. One thing only I knew not: a fair belt, as it were of linked golden leaves, about his waist.

**We can therefore conclude (1) that Boromir's shield was destroyed during his fight with the Orcs, and (2) that he didn't leave Gondor with it but instead picked it up somewhere between his departure from Gondor and arrival in Rivendell, perhaps in Rohan**.

By this reasoning the shield that Boromir arrived in Rivendell with was not a standard Gondorian shield, but Tolkien doesn't actually describe what these look like, so we can't say much on that count.

Tolkien *does* however describe what shields from Rohan look like, in his description of the arming of Aragorn and Legolas before Helm's Deep:

> Now men came bearing raiment of war from the king's hoard and they arrayed Aragorn and Legolas in shining mail. Helms too they chose, and **round shields: their bosses were overlaid with gold and set with gems, green and red and white**.

Finally, adressing your question of "Is it common for a soldier to bear the same shield in all cases like a sword?", I would say "no".  A shield is a defensive item, it gets damaged, and when it is too damaged to be useful any more it will be thrown away and replaced.

Comment: I should add: Tolkien *did* write a more detailed description of what each member of the Fellowship looked like and what gear they had, as a result of his unhappiness with Pauline Baynes' attempt at a drawing of them on her map, but that description is unfortunately unpublished.

Comment: As the favored son of Denethor, it can be assumed that Boromir would have the best armor & shield that Gondor's smiths could provide.

Comment: If I can inquire a little more, by what logic can we say that the shield he is seen with he did not carry from Gondor? How do we know it was picked up along the way?

Comment: @Rengald - it's given in my answer.  His shield didn't go on the boat, but yet Faramir didn't miss it.

Comment: The logic seems to go: If Boromir had left with a given shield, then Faramir would have known about it; and therefore, seeing Boromir in the funeral boat *without* the shield, Faramir would have missed it; since he doesn't state that he missed Boromir's shield, it follows that Boromir didn't have one.

Comment: Or that, as Darth Satan points out, there wasn't anything remarkable about his shield so it wasn't something Faramir would have mentioned, any more than he would have mentioned Boromir's socks. A shield is a disposable piece of standard gear.

Comment: @JoeL. - both are valid explanations.

Comment: It's not widely appreciated, but shields don't last. They have a way of getting hacked to pieces in the course of a battle or two. This is why, although swords get named and passed down, shields don't. As a result, one's shield would not be identifiable, and its lack would not be remarkable.

Comment: Besides all of this, a shield is heavy. You probably would not consider taking it on a long journey expecting no major battle and no reason to fear anything more than wolves and outlaws.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast not strictly true. There are ceremonial shields that are handed down. Indeed Theoden gives Gimli his and it is considered a generous gift

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast But he chose a cap of iron and leather that fitted well upon his round head; and a small shield he also took. It bore the running horse, white upon green, that was the emblem of the House of Eorl. ‘May it keep you well!’ said Théoden. ‘It was made for me in Thengel’s day, while still I was a boy.’